# Error showing SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, select

I've created a table named "Client"inside a database named "Database", but when I try to show the result of a certain select query, it gives me the error

> "Error    1   'System.Data.DataRow' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string myConnection = 
            "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=abc;password=xyz";

        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);
        MySqlDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        myDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(
            "select * from  Database.Client", myConn);

        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(myDataAdapter);
        myConn.Open();

    //    MessageBox.Show("Connected");

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataRow dr = new DataRow();
        DataTable dt;

        myDataAdapter.Fill(ds, "Client");
        dt = ds.Tables["Client"];
        dr = dt.Rows[0];

        dg.DataSource = ds.Tables["Client"];

        myConn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the exception raised? The code seems to be fine.

Comment: In which line are you getting that error? Looking at your code there is nothing that could throw that exception.

Answer (score 1):

The `DataRow` has [no public constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.datarow%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So this doesn't work:

```
DataRow dr = new DataRow();
```

Instead initialize it from the `DataRowCollection`-indexer later:

```
DataRow dr = null;
// ...
dr = dt.Rows[0];
```

However, the compiler error should be different( .... *is inaccessible due to its protection level*).

Answer (score 0):

You can not create a new instance DataRow. So remove this line:

```
DataRow dr = new DataRow();
```

And do this instead on this line:

```
var dr = dt.Rows[0];
```

Or you could type identify it like this:

```
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
```

Comment: You can *declare* a variable of type `DataRow`, but you can not *create a new instance* by calling a constructor.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar : You are right. I update the answer